# Determine if XML file conforms to a specific schema

Tags: c#, xml, schema, xsd

I have an System.IO.Stream object that may or may not be XML.

What is the quickest/easiest way to determine if 
   1) Is this file XML and
   2) if it is, then is it an instance of a particular schema?

In the end I really just trying to write a method that can return true or false if a particular Stream is an instance of a schema.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307379

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you try to load is an `XDocument`, and then use [`XDocument.Validate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.extensions.validate.aspx). Return false if either the parsing or validation fails. There's some [sample code on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387037.aspx) which does something pretty similar, and which would be a good starting point.